# How to access serial port of client system through Chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, serial-port, google-chrome-app

I'm writing a framework that analyzes an IOT device connected to the client's PC. I want to do a JavaScript implementation of the analysis, graphing, etc., but I need access to the client's serial port's data bytes. So I found that Chrome apps are one way to do this. What I don't understand is how do I send the bytes received in the serial port (the *background.js* in the app already has a buffer of this) to the webpage? I'm able to send a message from my webpage to the app. But vice versa does not seem to work using Chrome's `onMessage` `await` (says undefined TypeError). I'm wondering if my understanding of the problem and my solution to it are correct.

Comment: Chrome extensions can't access serial ports, see https://crbug.com/654590. You'll have to write an additional native OS utility that uses [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to communicate with your extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm, serial ports are already accessible from the extension. Tried and tested. Thanks for your link! I'll wait for other replies from who've worked with this.

Comment: Serial ports are accessible in chrome apps, not extensions.

Comment: You have stated that you have "tried and tested" what you are doing. Thus, you know what you are creating, but are just calling it an extension, when it's an app. Thus, I have edited your question to change your mentions of extension to app, as it appears to be a terminology issue and not directly relevant to the problem you are having.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome apps this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the heads up. I started reading up about the difference and it seems the apps in chrome are soon to be discontinued (in 2018).